# How do I dynamically insert a string into a text file in PowerShell?

Tags: html, powershell, parsing, concatenation

The text is an html file. The line I am interested in looks something like:

```
<td>INC1234</td><td>INC1235</td><td>INC1236</td>
```

The **INC numbers** are different from file to file. I'd like to parse through the line by saying something like:

```
if like <td>INC, then concatenate '<td><a href="https://www.website.com/=' + INC# + '>"
```

To give an output like:

```
<td><a href="https://www.website.com/=INC1234>INC1234</a></td><td><a href="https://www.website.com/=INC1235>INC1235</a></td><td><a href="https://www.website.com/=INC1236>INC1236</a></td>"
```

EDIT1: Ok, if I do something like:

```
$parse = (-split (Get-Content -Raw C:\Temp\report.txt) -match '<td>INC')
$parse
```

It will find the characters, but it will return the entire line rather than looking for more that match the 'INC'. Presumably because they all reside on the same line with no spaces.

EDIT2: Maybe this will help. What I'm doing is using PowerShell to write SQL commands, send it to our SQL Server, return the data and use PSWriteHTML to build the report which works fantastic. But I am wanting the first column, which is the ticket number (eg. INC1234) to be a link to the ticket it reads.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
   [string]$ReportName
)


## Build the query box
function Read-MultiLineInputBoxDialog([string]$Message, [string]$WindowTitle, [string]$DefaultText)
{
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

    ## Create the Label.
    $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
    $label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
    $label.AutoSize = $true
    $label.Text = $Message

    ## Create the TextBox used to capture the user's text.
    $textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40)
    $textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(575,200)
    $textBox.AcceptsReturn = $true
    $textBox.AcceptsTab = $false
    $textBox.Multiline = $true
    $textBox.ScrollBars = 'Both'
    $textBox.Text = $DefaultText

    ## Create the OK button.
    $okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(415,250)
    $okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
    $okButton.Text = "OK"
    $okButton.Add_Click({ $form.Tag = $textBox.Text; $form.Close() })

    ## Create the Cancel button.
    $cancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $cancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(510,250)
    $cancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
    $cancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
    $cancelButton.Add_Click({ $form.Tag = $null; $form.Close() })

    ## Create the form.
    $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $form.Text = $WindowTitle
    $form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(610,320)
    $form.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedSingle'
    $form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    $form.AutoSizeMode = 'GrowAndShrink'
    $form.Topmost = $True
    $form.AcceptButton = $okButton
    $form.CancelButton = $cancelButton
    $form.ShowInTaskbar = $true

    ## Add all of the controls to the form.
    $form.Controls.Add($label)
    $form.Controls.Add($textBox)
    $form.Controls.Add($okButton)
    $form.Controls.Add($cancelButton)

    ## Initialize and show the form.
    $form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
    $form.ShowDialog() > $null  # Trash the text of the button that was clicked.

    ## Return the text that the user entered.
    return $form.Tag
}

## Prompt the SQL Query Box
$Query = Read-MultiLineInputBoxDialog -Message "Enter SQL Query Here" -WindowTitle "SQL Query" -DefaultText "SELECT FROM"
if ($Query -eq $null) { Break }
else { Write-Host "You entered the following text: $Query" }

## Pass query to SQL Server
$Pass = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Query -ServerInstance "MY-SERVER-INSTANCE" -Username "USERNAME" -Password "PASSWORD"

## Output the report and save to the network under the specified name
New-HTML {
    New-HTMLTable -EnableColumnReorder -DisableInfo -DataTable $Pass -ExcludeProperty "RowError", "RowState", "Table", `
    "ItemArray", "HasErrors" -HideFooter -PagingLength 25 -SearchBuilder

    New-HTMLTableStyle -FontFamily Calibri -FontSize 15 -FontStyle normal -TextAlign center -TextColor "#0a0a0a"
    New-HTMLTableStyle -FontFamily Calibri -BackgroundColor "#fffdb5" -FontSize 15px -TextColor "#0a0a0a" -TextAlign center -Type RowHover
    
} -ShowHTML -FilePath "\\Server\$ReportName.html" -Online
```

The report looks something like:

```
Ticket:       Description:
----------------------------
INC1234       Broken Monitor
INC1235       No Sound
```

The HTML that PSWriteHTML builds throws all of the ticket numbers on one line so I would like to edit that HTML with the `<a href="">` tag to dynamically create links for each ticket # mainly because I don't know how to do it in PS and can't seem to find a good answer through Google - which is why I came here.

Comment: Sounds easy enough. Where are you running into issues?

Comment: @DougMaurer I've never done concatenating in PowerShell before and I'm also not sure how to dynamically do this. Since each HTML file will have different INC numbers, I'm not sure how to parse through the line, read the INC#, insert the href portion and move on to the next one.

Comment: We all started from a place of not knowing how. I'd recommend starting with [these](https://shorturl.at/ijHQ0) and give it a go. If you run into a brick wall after giving a reasonable effort, then share your code and any errors/details. This [link](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-strings/) seems like a good one for the task at hand.

Comment: Are the table cells (`<td>...</td>`) always on a single line, 3 of them in a row, like in your example?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes. It comes from PSWriteHTML generating an HTML report through PowerShell. If I open the generated HTML file, all of the INC tickets are on one line.

Comment: If you don't know how to start, break the problem down into smaller problems: 1. Read a file into a variable using `Get-Content`. 2. Safe the variable back to another file using `Set-Content`. 3. Replace text in a variable using the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#replacement-operator) operator. 4. Combine 1..3. -- For quick testing and explanation of RegEx there are many online tools like https://regex101.com/

Comment: @zett42 I'm using ```Get-Content``` to read the file and also done it to return each character into an array. But I can't seem to find anything through my Googling having to do with dynamically finding the next few characters in the string but not going passed the next '<' character, storing it in a variable, pasting the data back between what I was searching for, then moving on.

Comment: If it’s coming from pswritehtml then that means you’re feeding it nice structured data. Why try to pull out of this output vs grabbing it before it’s html?

Comment: @DougMaurer If I knew how to do that, that would be great. The ultimate goal is to have each INC# in the "Ticket" column a hyperlink to the actual ticket itself that users can click. So this is just a single step in manipulating ~25k data cells with hyperlinks dynamically.

Comment: So you’re not the one using pswritehtml?

Answer (score 0):

Although not familiar with PsWriteHtml, I guess you could simply change the `Ticket` properties in the array you receive in `$Pass`:

```
## Pass query to SQL Server
$Pass = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Query -ServerInstance "MY-SERVER-INSTANCE" -Username "USERNAME" -Password "PASSWORD"

# convert all Tickets into hyperlinks
foreach ($item in $Pass) { 
    $item.Ticket = '<a href="https://www.website.com/={0}>{0}</a>'-f $item.Ticket 
}
```

Then the rest of your code

```
## Output the report and save to the network under the specified name
New-HTML {...}
```